# Retrieve data from SQLite database Android using Xamarin

Tags: sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm simply trying to retrieve data from SQLite, but my code neither returns a value nor gives an error. Please help me out.
So far I've done

```
var test = new List<cdProdGroup>();
var db = new SQLiteConnection(path);

var test1 = db.Query<cdProdGroup>("SELECT * FROM cdProdGroup");
foreach (var item in test1) {
    cdProdGroup cd = new cdProdGroup { 
        DIQ_PG_CD_EBS = item.DIQ_PG_CD_EBS,  
        DIQ_PG_DESC = item.DIQ_PG_DESC,  
        DVSN_CD = item.DVSN_CD
    };

    test.Add(cd);
}
```

I'm using Xamarin for coding

Comment: Are you sure the path to your db is correct?  Are you sure your db has data in it?  How are you seeding your data - is it seeded by your app in code, or are you deploying a pre-seeded db with your app?

Comment: Its pre-seeded, and yes db is also having data in it. Also debugger gets out from the line whr query is defined.

Comment: Fixed a little spelling and grammar; changed indentation and spacing in code for easier reading.

Comment: What's the error you are getting?

Comment: Open the database in a tool like [sqlite browser](http://sqlitebrowser.org/) and execute the `SELECT * FROM cdProdGroup` query in it. It'll highlight if the query has an error.

Answer (score 0):

The `SELECT * FROM cdProdGroup` query is unnecessary as is the re-assignment into a new `List<cdProdGroup>`.

You can simplify the query like so:

```
var db = new SQLiteConnection(path);
var test = db.Table<cdProdGroup>().ToList();
```